# Windows SDK is not installed

Tags: windows, winapi

I installed the Windows SDK from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34860

When I run `regedit.exe`, I do not see a `Microsoft SDKs` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft`.

Comment: Do you have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs`?

Comment: See [Windows SDK Registry Keys](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssdk/2008/05/28/windows-sdk-registry-keys/).

Comment: Your link points to Windows Server 2012 Essentials SDK, which is not the regular Win SDK. You may download regular [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) instead.

Comment: @zett42

I installed the sdk from [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), now I am able to find the sdk's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDK. But still my build fails with a missing SDK error.

Comment: @MichaelGunter

I installed the sdk from [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk), now I am able to find the sdk's HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDK. But still my build fails with a missing SDK error.

Comment: What are you trying to build? If Visual C++, what platform toolset is your project set up to use?

Comment: @MichaelGunter
I'm trying to build a .net application using Teamcity. Here's the error I get:

**************************

error MSB3086: Task could not find "LC.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.6\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

Comment: @MichaelGunter
MS Build Tools 2015, version 14.0